# Xlsx Writer: Writing strings with multiple format in a single cell

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have a string with multiple semicolons.

```
'firstline: abc \n secondline: bcd \n thirdline: efg'
```

I want to write this strings in excel cell using Xlsx Writer like below.

**firstline**: abc 
**secondline**: bcd 
**thirdline**: efg

This is what I did.

```
description_combined = 
    '''
    firstline: abc
    secondline: bcd
    thirdline: efg
    '''
    spanInserted = []
    spanInserted = description_combined.split("\n")
    result = ''

    for spans in spanInserted:
        strr1 =  '{}:'.format(spans.split(":")[0])
        strr2 = spans.split(":")[1]
        result += '''bold , "{}" , "{}" ,'''.format(str(strr1),str(strr2))

    result = result[:-1]
    # print result

    worksheet.write_rich_string('A1', result)
```

This is the result I got in excel cell:

> bold , "firstline:" , "abc" ,bold , "secondline:" , "bcd" ,bold , "thirdline:" , "efg"

Comment: Would you like one row or three rows?

Comment: @Giordano I wanted dynamic rows using split of a single string. Answer by jmcnamara worked.

Comment: Ok @Manoj, I have posted a dynamic solution. I hope will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jmcnamara's solution works well. I posted a similar possible solution, but dynamic.

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("<your path>")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
# add style for first column
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
text_wrap = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True, 'valign': 'top'})
data = []
description_combined = 'firstline: abc \n secondline: bcd \n thirdline: efg'
# prepare list of list
for item in description_combined.split("\n"):
    data.append(cell_format)
    data.append(item.split(":")[0].strip() + ":")
    data.append(item.split(":")[1] + "\n")

# write data in one single cell
data.append(text_wrap)

worksheet.write_rich_string('A1', *data)

workbook.close()
```

I hope that will be helpful

Answer (score 8):

The [`write_string()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-rich-string) method takes a list as an argument but you are passing a string.

You should use something like this to pass your list of strings and formats:

```
result = [bold, 'firstline: ',  'abc',
          bold, 'secondline: ', 'bcd',
          bold, 'thirdline: ',  'efg']

worksheet.write_rich_string('A1', *result)
```

However, if you also want the text to be wrapped you will need to add a `text_wrap` cell format at the end of the list and add newlines for where you want the wrap to occur. Something like this:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('rich_strings.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)
worksheet.set_row(0, 60)

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
text_wrap = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True, 'valign': 'top'})

result = [bold, 'firstline: ',  'abc\n',
          bold, 'secondline: ', 'bcd\n',
          bold, 'thirdline: ',  'efg']

result.append(text_wrap)

worksheet.write_rich_string('A1', *result)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]